# How to fix the jslint message: variable is already defined

Tags: javascript

I was trying to implement the following code:

```
var action = function (e) {     
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    container.objet.hide();
}
```

But jslint complains about the following:

`'e' is already defined. var e = window.event;`

What is the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: As a side note, isn't using event as your function name going to cause problems since event already exists in the global scope (window.event)?

Comment: Just skip the var statement: e = window.event;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a named argument creates a locally scoped variable (which is what `var` does). Since you have an argument `e` and you use `var e` you are trying to create the variable twice.

Remove the `var` from where you use `e` the third time time.

```
var event = function (e) {      // First time
    if (!e) {                   // Second time
        e = window.event;       // Third time
```

Comment: how about replacing the if with: e = e | window.event;

Answer (score 0):

In the function, actually e has been defined as argument. so when you define some variable same as arguments, it will complains.